# How can I use multiple variables(paramaters) in a url in django

Tags: python, regex, django

I can get the *filler* variable from the URL below just fine.

```
url(r'^production/(?P<filler>\w{7})/$', views.Filler.as_view()),
```

In my view I can retrieve the *filler* as expected. However, if I try to do use a URL like the one below.

```
url(r'^production/(?P<filler>)\w{7}/(?P<day>).*/$', views.CasesByDay.as_view()),
```

Both variables (filler, day) are blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the entire parameter in parenthesis. It looks like you did that in your first example but not the second.

Try:

```
url(r'^production/(?P<filler>\w{7})/(?P<day>.*)/$', views.CasesByDay.as_view()),
```

See the official documentation for more information and examples: [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get enough sleep or something, I should have caught a mistake like that.